# Cannot Find Civicrm.settings.php file

Tags: drupal, installation, configuration

I'm relatively new to CiviCRM so this might sound like a question with an obvious answer.

I have set up my cron for my drupal CiviCRM site with easycron.com and have found that it always reports back the same error:

```
Could not load the settings file at: /home/content/06/10588406/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/../../../default/civicrm.settings.php
```

Now, I have gone through and verified that I have followed the instructions (I even created a new site with absolutely no purpose other than to test this issue with civicrm) and it come up with this error too. All of the requirements are met, permissions checked, everything...

So what can I do to change this? Is there anything I can hardcode into the civicrm config file? Or does anyone know where I might find the directory that it's currently looking in to paste a copy of the civicrm settings file (currently located in /sites/default) into it?

Thank you!

Matt

Comment: I'm using the drupal cron for CiviCrm too. It's a drupal module: (https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_cron). It works like a charm. Maybe this fits your needs as well, if max. one cron per hour is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion of @Volker - this module Drupal Cron for CiviCrm (drupal.org/project/civicrm_cron) appears to do the work I need it to. However, I'm still going to try and work on as to why going through the cron.php function of CiviCRM fails when this new module works.

Answer (score 1):

the path suggests a problem which i can't suggest the fix for, but if it helps I would expect to have the civicrm module at

/sites/all/modules/civicrm

which it looks like you have but the settings file would be at

/sites/default

not at

sites/all/modules/civicrm/../../../default/civicrm.settings.php

Comment: Yes, currently the settings file is located at /sites/default and the module is located at /sites/all/modules/civicrm which is why it concerns me that this error is even popping up.